# Programmatically Click Row Header in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am searching everywhere for code to programmatically Click a specific DataGridView row header, after processing a certain code sequence.

Everything I have found allows to select or highlight a row, column or cell; but nothing to date Clicks the Row Header ie. fires the

```
private void dgvMyGrid_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {}
```

Method.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `dgvMyGrid_RowHeaderMouseClick(this, null);` ?

Comment: Try setting the `sender` as `DataGridRowHeader` you want to "click"

Comment: You could inherit your component from DataGridView and call OnRowHeaderMouseClick() method inside - this should emulate real click (although DGV is full of surprises). Of course you have to create correct event arguments.

Comment: Did you resolve your problems?

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

To simply make the code in the dgvMyGrid_RowHeaderMouseClick run in the simplest way, as Tzah Mama wrote, it is enough to write:

```
dgvMyGrid_RowHeaderMouseClick(null, null);
```

Note 1: It is important to add a coment to the event code to **document** that it can be called in this special and not normal way. Especially since this doesn't provide the parameters the code might expect.

Note 2: If your code needs some of the parameters you can try to provide them:

- It is trivial to provide the `sender` simply as `dgvMyGrid`
- If you are not coding a DataGridView instance but an inherited class you replace the dvg name simply with `this`
- The second parameter is complex and not all its parts can be easily provided, but probably are not needed either.

Here is the basic code to create it:

```
int row = ??    // your target row
int col= -1;    // no column
int x = 0;      // no offsets..
int y = 0;      // ..
int delta = 0; // no mouse wheel

DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs E = new DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs(col, row, x, y,
                          new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, clicks, x, y, delta));
```

Note 3: Sometimes it is important to know whether an event has been called by a real user action or by code. Leaving a paremter null is a simple  way to signal this. Again: Key is **documentation**!

But maybe you need the **effect** of the rowHeader click? Which may be a row select, depending on the SelectionMode. This will **not** work by calling the script! Instead you must code the select as well:

```
 DGV1.Rows[row ].Selected = true;
```